# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in template string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, template-strings

I have some html that I converted into a template string and getting the above error when I check the checkbox, I know it has to do with the ${currentRow}, just not sure why its acting this way

```
function RowChecked(row) {
    ...
}

const currentRow = ds.find(f => f.ItemID === itemId);
return `<input id='${currentRow.Area}_${currentRow.ItemKey}' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onChange='RowChecked(${currentRow})' />`;
```

Comment: `onChange='RowChecked(${currentRow})'` so you are trying to pass in the object??

Comment: @epascarello, yes, sorry I should have added that into my question

Comment: Putting the whole object in that is a pretty bad idea. There is probably a better solution out there, but hard to tell without knowing all the code.

Comment: It used to be that you had to use `className` and not just `class`, but that may have changed

Comment: @Pointy you can use class when building html as a string....

Comment: @epascarello, I was originally sending an id over with 'this.id', then was doing a search through the grid data to get the currentRow that way but seemed like this would be faster

Comment: oh of course, duhh

Comment: Better solution is probably not build strings, but if you want to you need to use JSON.stringify

Answer (score 2):

I would not do this, but you would need to use JSON.stringify

```
return `<input id='${currentRow.Area}_${currentRow.ItemKey}' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onChange='RowChecked(${JSON.stringify(currentRow)})' />`;
```

but this will fail if one of the values has a `'` in it.

Better solution would be to generate DOM elements and add them to the DOM. You could add event handlers which references the object.

Next best thing would build up a map/object of ids and reference the record by the id.

Looking at your code you are doing a lot of looping to find the record.

```
ds.find(f => f.ItemID)
```

So if you just make it an object it turns into a simple look up

```
const lookup = ds.reduce((acc, f) => { acc[f.ItemID] = f; return acc; }, {});
```

Now in your code you can pass the id and get it. That find code goes away, you just reference the object by the id.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, and what you're getting at.

Comment: The checkboxes are in a grid, each row has one, I could have just used the databound event in the grid that I am using too now that I think more about it

Comment: I added something to the answer on what I would do. Make a an object with the ids as the key and everything is a simple look up and not a loop. You take a penalty of the reduce once, no need to loop all over the place.